# JavaScript instance vs prototype methods and heap snapshot data using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

I have a heap profile taken in Chrome Dev Tools, but I am not sure how to interpret the data. As a test, I created 10,000 WidgetBuilder objects, each with their own methods. I would like to profile out storing methods on instances versus the prototype and see how that affects memory and performance when my page loads.

1. Should I focus on Retained Size or Shallow Size?
2. Are the values listed in these columns in bytes?
3. What is considered a lot of memory?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to start here:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling

It goes into detail on how to understand what you're reading. As for what is considered a lot of memory that's a tricky question. If your website is targeted at mobile devices I would start there as a constraint. To come up with a good comparison I'd suggest running the profiler against sites that you use every day and observe the memory consumption there.

If you find you're using more memory than gmail you might want to rethink ;)

I also recommend checking out jspref:

http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-instance-functions

There is a LOT of prior work done on that site in regards to performance testing. You might be able to save yourself some time.

Comment: I did see the docs before and it says: "The size of memory that is held by the object itself is called shallow size." and "The Retained Size column displays the maximum retained size among the same set of objects." I am not clear on the differences between those 2 statements. Any idea?

Comment: First link on google: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/memory-analysis-101 The tldr; is shallow is how much memory the object itself is consuming and retained is how much memory the object is preventing from being garbage collected. If the object has references to other objects then those other objects must remain in memory until the first object is gone.